# Adding a variable to current value of field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

How would I create the following statement in MySQL/CodeIgniter?

> Update the current value of "food" with variable $sell. So the result would be the value of "food" + $sell.

EDIT: Ok, I finally figured it out using CodeIgniters Active Record Class

```
$food_up = "food +" . $sell; 
$this->db->set('food', $food_up, FALSE)
         ->where('user_id', $uid);
$this->db->update('market');
```

Thank you for your suggestions ;)

Comment: When you post an assignment or test question as this appears to be, please also post the code you have tried so far. You will not receive much assistance without evidence of a solid effort. We're happy to help you where stuck, but won't typically provide a complete answer for homework.

Comment: Isn't this what *you* are supposed to do? Maybe the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax.html) helps.

Comment: This was not a homework btw, I figured it out by reading CodeIgniter's User Guide, section about Active Record Class in DB Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is going to be a combination of an [`update`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) and modifying the result using [`string literals`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html) and [variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) in MySQL.

```
UPDATE <table_name>
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
```

You are going to need to figure out how to "set" your column to the current value + a string literal.  Your question does look a little confusing and its hard to tell if you actually need a variable or not, or if you are just appending something to the current value...

Answer (score 0):

`update table1 set colFood = colFood + @variableName where foodId = @myFoodId`

or

`update table1 set colFood = @variableName where foodId = @myFoodId`